# ssrs passing a boolean parameter in drilldown

Tags: reporting-services

l am working on a project where l have to pass parameters to a drill down report . l have managed to pass all parameters except 1 which is Boolean ,so far l have added it to the series parameters list but still not working.please help

Answer (score 0):

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a143c409-3d53-4461-90f0-e22eef8cfaf9/how-to-pass-through-a-parameter-which-is-not-a-field-query?forum=sqlreportingservices

l was just having a dumb moment , this works